# In librdkafka, dr_cb() is called each time after produce() called

Tags: c++, apache-kafka

I am working on C++ Kafka client: librdkafka. The lib is here https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.cpp.
Each time **produce() in Producer class** is called, is the **dr_cb()** function (see the following code) called?

```
/**
* Delivery Report callback class
*/
class DeliveryReportCb {
public:
virtual void dr_cb (Message &message) = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delivery report callbacks (`dr_cb`) are only called when the application calls `poll()` on the Producer handle, they are not called from within the `produce()` call.

Comment: Thanks. When produce() called, it will return **ErrorCode** to indicate success or failure. Does **success** mean the message was sent to Kafka server OR just mean the message was sent to the out queue? Is there an out queue at the client side?

Comment: I tested my program. I produced 234 messages. In total, poll(0) was called 234 times. poll(1000) was called 2 times. But dr_cb() was called 234 times. Looks wrong....

Comment: @ChengchengPei produce() is an asynchronous API, so when **Success** is returned from produce() it means the message was accepted and appended to an internal queue, it will be transmitted to the broker eventually (depending on config and network status). Consequently a produce() call quickly followed by a poll() call will most likely **NOT** trigger dr_cb() for the message just sent since it is still in an internal queue, it might serve a dr_cb() for **any number** of previous messages that are now delivered (or failed) though.

Comment: Thanks. How to check whether one message is sent to the broker eventually? Check the out queue size by **outq_len()**?

Comment: If the message is in the internal queue, it is guaranteed that this message will be sent to the broker?

Comment: @ChengchengPei You use the delivery report callback to know when a message has been succesfully delivered or failed permanently. `outq_len()` returns the number of messages awaiting transmission to the broker (i.e., the internal queue length).

Comment: @ChengchengPei Yes, a message accepted by `produce()` is guaranteed to be delivered to the broker within the constraints of `message.timeout.ms` (waiting for leader broker to become available) and `message.send.max.retries` (messages will be retried upon temporary errors, but fail immediately on permanent errors).

Comment: If I set message.send.max.retries to 0, it means that it will try forever until the message is sent?  Thanks

Comment: @ChengchengPei No, 0 means no retries, to get "indefinite" retries set the value to 10000000.

Comment: do you have this problem before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547644/too-many-messages-lost-when-kafka-brokers-restarted     Sometimes, after I restarted the broker, all the messages in the out queue were lost. They should be sent to broker, but not.

Comment: @Edenhill Why calling `poll()` is needed? This ruins the async nature of `produce()` because forces you to actively check if response is back. Is there a true async `produce()` in RDKafka, like in java API, where you initiate a produce request and provide a callback which will be called when request is done, without bothering you with some additional work?

Comment: @MichalWegorek You need to call poll() to serve those delivery callbacks (since callbacks can't be spontaneously called), but it is up to you when to call it - you dont need to call it after each produce() call, it is typically called from the app's main loop or from a separate thread.