# how to re-send a failed message properly in librdkafka?

Tags: c++, c, apache-kafka, librdkafka

```
static void DeliverCallback(rd_kafka_t *rk,  void *payload, size_t len, rd_kafka_resp_err_t error_code,  void *opaque, void *msg_opaque)
{
    if (error_code != RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR)
    {
            // todo resend the message

    }
}
```

my dr_cb is like this.  I know how to get the content of the failed-to-be-sent mesasge, but how do I get the topic?  what's the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: Did you check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461978/in-librdkafka-dr-cb-is-called-each-time-after-produce-called)

Answer (score 2):

The `dr_cb` interface is old and deprecated, you should use the richer `dr_msg_cb` instead, where you have access to all the `rd_kafka_message_t` fields, for your case the `rkmessage->rkt` for the topic.

But, you typically should not retry producing a message on failure in a delivery report, since librdkafka will have done all in its power to produce the message within the configured constraints (`message.timeout.ms` and `retries`), there isn't much value the application can add by retrying the same message again.

Instead configure `message.timeout.ms` to accommodate your business needs, answering the question "How long does it make sense to try producing this piece of data?", and set `retries` to its maximum value (since the number of retries is irrelevant from an application perspective).

If duplicates or message ordering is critical you should also look into using the idempotent producer (`enable.idempotence=true`).

And finally, librdkafka provides a message persistance indicator API (`rd_kafka_message_status()`) for each delivered or failed message, letting the application know if the message was..:

- definitely not persisted
- possibly persisted (a manual retry may cause duplicates)
- definitely persisted

See https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md#message-reliability for more information on message reliablity in librdkafka.